# Suggestions - Enabling EFS on FileStream Data for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, filestream

If anyone has already tried enabling EFS on FileStream data for multiple databases around 500 GB+, please share your thoughts on feasibility or issues / considerations we should keep in mind.

We are in process of enabling EFS for PROD. We are testing in lower environments too.

**Specifically, which one is better - enabling parallel EFS, or enabling EFS on one FileStream Folder at a time?**

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to whether or not EFS should be applied per folder.  However, there is a security consideration that seems to be worth an answer here.

Check out this post from [David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft) on the MSDN forums question [Can FILESTREAM directory containers be encrypted with EFS?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd5acaca-9911-4168-a82d-02a92c0d5a80/can-filestream-directory-containers-be-encrypted-with-efs?forum=sqlsecurity):

> Note that during a SQL Server backup of FILESTREAM data, the data is stored decrypted. A restore operation to a normal volume therefore will result in decrypted values.

So if you are using native SQL Server backups, you will need to keep this caveat in mind from a security / compliance standpoint.